# Can not run Redis commands using StackExchangeRedis

Tags: asp.net-core, connection, stackexchange.redis

Hello i am trying to connect to a `Redis` database  from a `ASP NET Core 3.1` application and i keep getting this error when i issue a command.

```
> 'No connection is active/available to service this operation: SET a; A
> blocking operation was interrupted by a call to
> WSACancelBlockingCall., mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available,
> clientName: [ClientName], IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=8,Max=1000),
> WORKER:
```

I think it has something to do with the library `StackExchangeRedis` since until now it worked, up until it stopped working randomly.I have updated to the last version, restarted pc, whatever and nothing.

I can connect to my local redis and issue commands with both the `Redis-Cli` and using `telnet 127.0.0.1 6379` , so that is why i think the culprit is the library.

**ConnectionString**

```
localhost:6379,ssl=True,allowAdmin=True,abortConnect=False,defaultDatabase=0
```

**How i use it:**

```
var con=ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString); //passes
con.GetDatabase().StringSet("a","a"); //throws
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just using it for localhost development purposes you can try disabling ssl : `localhost:6379,**ssl=false**,allowAdmin=True,abortConnect=False,defaultDatabase=0`